# A CRM architecture (open source app)

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, crm

I need to develop a CRM application, but I don't know how the architecture should be layed out. Can anyone point me to a high level or detailed outline of how such a project can be developed?

Comment: If you are developing an OpenSource CRM solution, have you looked at any of the existing CRMs to see if they fit your needs. Sugar CRM is a pretty popular solution.  They have an opensource edition (http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/download/sugar-suite.html)

Comment: @RobGoodwin do you have a link to the source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CRM is not really anything magical.  It is just a database application that is centered around customers.  If I was you I would sign up for trials with some of the big players in the established crm industry.  [Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/), [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/), [Saleslogix](http://www.sagecrmsolutions.com/products/sagesaleslogix) to randomly name a few (there are thousands more).  The best advice I personally have is, start with a basic customer record and then make everything else a plug-able extension.  No 2 companies are going to really use a CRM system the same way.  The more flexibility you can provide, that wider use your application will enjoy (*imo obviously*).