# Architectural choices for a CRM

Tags: .net-core, domain-driven-design, microservices, crm, cqrs

I am looking for some light in the complexity of architectural selection, before starting the development of a CMS or CRM or ERP.

I was able to find this similar question: [A CRM architecture (open source app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796442/a-crm-architecture-open-source-app)
But it seems old enough.

I watch and read recently several conferences, discussions about monolith vs distrubuted, DDD philosophy, CQRS and event driven design, etc.
And I panic even more than before on the architectural choice, having taken into account the flaws of each (I think).

What I find unfortunate with all the examples of microservices and distributed systems that can be found easily on the net is that they always take e-commerce as an example (Customers, Orders, Products ...). And for this kind of example, several databases (in general, a NoSQL DB by microservice) exist.
I see the advantage (more or less) ==> to keep a minimalist representation of the necessary data for each context.

But how to go for a unique and relational database? I really think I need a single relational database, having worked in a company producing a CRM (without access to the source code of the machine, but the structure of the database), I could see the importance of relational: necessary for listings, reports, and consult the links between entities within the CRM (a contact can have several companies and conversely, each user has several actions, tasks, but each of his tasks can also be assigned to other users, or even be linked to other items such as: "contact", "company", "publication", "calendarDate", etc. And there can be a lot of records in each table (+ 100,000 rows), so the choice of indexes will be quite important, and transactions are omni-present because there will be a lot of concurrent access to data records).

What I'm saying to myself is that if I choose to use a microservice system, there will be a lot of microservices to do because there would really be a lot of different contexts, and a high probability of having a bunch of different domain models. And then I will end up having the impression of having to light each small bulb of a garland, with perhaps too much process running simultaneously.

To try to be precise and not go in all directions, I have 2 questions to ask:

1. Can we easily mix the DDD philosophy with a monolith system, while uncoupling very small quantity (for the eventual services that should absolutely be set apart, for various reasons)?
   If so, could I ask for resources where I can learn a lot more about this?
2. Do we necessarily have to work with a multitude of databases, and should it necessarily be of the kind mongoDb, nosql?
   I can imagine that the answer is no, but could I ask to elaborate a little more? Or redirect me to articles that will give me clear enough answers?

Thank you in advance !

(It would be .NET Core, draft is here: https://github.com/Jin-K/simple-cms)

Answer (score 5):

DDD works perfectly as an approach in designing your CRM. I used it in my last project (a web-based CRM) and it was exactly what I needed. As a matter of fact, if I wouldn't have used DDD then it would have been impossible to manage. The CRM that I created (the only architect and developer) was very complex and very custom. It integrates with many external systems (i.e. with email server and phone calls system).

The first thing you should do is to discover the main parts of your system. This is the hardest part and you probably get them wrong the first time. The good thing is that this is an iterative process that should stabilize before it gets to production because then it is harder to refactor (i.e. you need to migrate data and this is painful). These main parts are called Bounded contexts (BC) in DDD.

For each BC I created a module. I didn't need microservices, a modular monolith was just perfect. I used the [Conway's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law) to discover the BCs. I noticed that every department had common but also different needs from the CRM.

There were some generic BCs that were common to each department, like email receiving/sending, customer activity recording, task scheduling, notifications. The behavior was almost the same for all departments.

The department specific BCs had very different behaviour for similar concepts. For example, the Sales department and Data processing department had different requirements for a Contract so I created two Aggregates named `Contract` that shared the same ID but they had other data+behavior. To keep them "synchronized" I used a Saga/Process manager. For example, when a Contract was activated (manually or after the first payment) then a `DataProcessingDocument` was created, containing data based on the contract's content.

Another important point of view is to discover and respect the sources of truth. For example, the source of truth for the received emails is the Email Server. The CRM should reflect this in its UI, it should be very clear that it is only a delayed reflection of what is happening on the Email Server; there may be received emails that are not shown in the CRM for technical reasons.

The source of truth for the draft emails is the CRM, with it's `Email composer` module. If a Draft is not shown anymore then it means that it has been deleted by a CRM user.

When the CRM is not the source of truth then the code should have little or no behavior and the data should be mostly immutable. Here you could have CRUD, unless you have performance problems (i.e. millions of entries) in which case you could use CQRS.

> And there can be a lot of records in each table (+ 100,000 rows), so the choice of indexes will be quite important, and transactions are omni-present because there will be a lot of concurrent access to data records).

CQRS helped my a lot to have a performant+responsive system. You don't have to use it for each module, just where you have a lot of data and/or different behavior for write and read. For example, for the recording of the activity with the customers, I used CQRS to have performant listings (so I used CQRS for performance reasons).

I also used CQRS where I had a lot of different views/projections/interpretations of the same events.

> Do we necessarily have to work with a multitude of databases, and should it necessarily be of the kind mongoDb, nosql? I can imagine that the answer is no, but could I ask to elaborate a little more? Or redirect me to articles that will give me clear enough answer

Of course not. Use whatever works. I used MongoDB in 95% of cases and Mysql only for the Search module. It was easier to manage only a database system and the performance/scalability/availability was good enough.

I hope these thoughts help you. Good luck!

Comment: I did not expected to receive such an elaborate response, and what a pleasure !
I didn't even know we could use CQRS in a modular monolith, I thought it was principally made to communicate between services: I'm really discovering all this principles :p
I will clearly start by following your advices: to try to discover the main parts of my system and inquire about the "Conway's Law" to identity BC.
Thank you for this !